Tail bound for Gaussian matrix
Let $X \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times n}$ be a Gaussian matrix with i.i.d $N(0,1)$ entries. Let $T$ be a finite subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$ such that for all $u \in T$, $\lVert u \rVert_2 = 1$.
Define $Z = \max_{u \in T} \lVert Xu \rVert_2^2$.
Prove that for all $t \geq 0$, $P(Z - EZ \geq 2 \sqrt{2t EZ} + 2t) \leq e^{-t}$.
The best I can do is using that $\lVert Xu \rVert_2^2$ is sub-exponential, $P( \max_{u \in T} \lVert Xu \rVert_2^2 \geq t) \leq 2 \left| T \right| \exp(-t/K)$ for some constant $K$.
Thank you.

